# css cursor url positioning

Tags: css

I have some css like this:

`cursor: url("x.gif"), move;`

but the problem is that the image is not positioned right, I'd like to move it -15px up and left for example.  Is this possible?

The center of a `cursor: move;` is the click point afaict and I'd like to use the center of my custom cursor image as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes - just supply the hotspot coordinates:

```
cursor: url("x.gif") 15 15, move;
```

However bear in mind that this will break some browsers. Ideally, you need:

```
cursor: url("x.cur"), move;
cursor: url("x.gif") 15 15, move;
```

Where `x.cur` is a "proper" cursor file. If you need a program to make one, try RealWorld Cursor Editor.